# a framework for testing the performance of Kafka cluster

Tags: testing, apache-kafka

Is there any comprehensive test framework for testing the performance of Kafka 2.12 cluster in which test done using a predefined dataset?

I looked at `Jmeter` and `Pepper-box` but it seems they don't fit my requirement

thanks in advance

Comment: Use Grafana with promethues to monitor realtime Kafka performance

Comment: thank you @sun007. but what about testing? something like kafka-producer-perf-test.sh but my requirements added to that

Comment: You can produces again load test data and visualize through grafana....get the numbers and re produce again..You need to create basic producer to publish/produce predefined data set

Comment: thank you @sun007 again. I check your solution that it satisfies my requirements and inform you. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually, both tools are used for performance testing of Kafka but Kafka also have the executable script to test the performance of Producer and Consumer.

```
kafka-producer-perf-test.sh

kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh
```

Setup

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --create \
  --topic test-rep-one \
  --partitions 6 \
  --replication-factor 1
bin/kafka-topics.sh \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --create \
  --topic test \
  --partitions 6 --replication-factor 3
```

**Producer**

A single thread, no replication

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
  --topic test \
  --num-records 50000000 \
  --record-size 100 \
  --throughput -1 \
  --producer-props acks=1 \
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
  buffer.memory=67108864 \
  batch.size=8196
```

Single-thread, async 3x replication

```
    bin/kafk-topics.sh \
  --zookeeper zookeeper.example.com:2181 \
  --create \
  --topic test \
  --partitions 6 \
  --replication-factor 3
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
  --topic test \
  --num-records 50000000 \
  --record-size 100 \
  --throughput -1 \
  --producer-props acks=1 \
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
  buffer.memory=67108864 \
  batch.size=8196
```

Single-thread, sync 3x replication

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
  --topic test \
  --num-records 50000000 \
  --record-size 100 \
  --throughput -1 \
  --producer-props acks=1 \
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
  buffer.memory=67108864 batch.size=64000
```

Three Producers, 3x async replication

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
  --topic test \
  --num-records 50000000 \
  --record-size 100 \
  --throughput -1 \
  --producer-props acks=1 \
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
  buffer.memory=67108864 \
  batch.size=8196
```

Throughput Versus Stored Data

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
  --topic test \
  --num-records 50000000 \
  --record-size 100 \
  --throughput -1 \
  --producer-props acks=1 \
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
  buffer.memory=67108864 batch.size=8196
```

Effect of message size

```
for i in 10 100 1000 10000 100000; do
  echo ""
  echo $i
  bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
    --topic test \
    --num-records $((1000*1024*1024/$i))\
    --record-size $i\
    --throughput -1 \
    --producer-props acks=1 \
    bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
    buffer.memory=67108864 \
    batch.size=128000
```

**Consumer**

Consumer throughput

```
bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --messages 50000000 \
  --topic test \
  --threads 1
```

3 Consumers On three servers, run:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --messages 50000000 \
  --topic test \
  --threads 1
```

End-to-end Latency

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh \
  kafka.tools.TestEndToEndLatency \
  localhost:9092 \
  localhost:2181 \
  test 5000
```

Producer and consumer

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh \
  org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance \

bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
  --topic test \
  --num-records 50000000 \
  --record-size 100 \
  --throughput -1 \
  --producer-props acks=1 \
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 \
  buffer.memory=67108864 \
  batch.size=8196

bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --messages 50000000 \
  --topic test \
  --threads 1
```